# Override KeyDown Event in wxPython

Tags: python, events, wxpython, keydown

I wrote wxTreeCtrl where I only want to handle keycodes between 65 and 90 (Ascii: A-Z).
And I dont want to handle any other keycodes by myself. After I handled the keys between 65 and 90, how am I able to abort my event and use the standard "key down"-event for the wxTreeCtrl?

Class definition:

```
class ConfigTreeCtrl(wx.TreeCtrl):
```

Method binding:

```
self.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.OnKeyDown, self)
```

Method definition:

```
def OnKeyDown(self, event):         
    now = time.time()  
    keyCode = event.GetKeyCode()
    if (keyCode >= 65 and keyCode <= 90) or ( keyCode >= 48 and keyCode <= 57):
        if self.searchString == "":
            self.searchString = chr(event.GetKeyCode())
        elif (now - self.lastKeyDown) < 2:
            self.searchString += str(chr(event.GetKeyCode()))
        else:
            self.searchString = str(chr(event.GetKeyCode()))
    self.lastKeyDown = now
    self.GetItem(self.searchString, self.GetRootItem())
```

Thanks for your help and best regards

Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`event.Skip()`](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Event-class.html#Skip) processes the event further either in the base wxWindows class or the native control. So in your method something like this should be introduced:

```
def OnKeyDown(self, event):         
    now = time.time()  
    keyCode = event.GetKeyCode()
    if (keyCode >= 65 and keyCode <= 90) or ( keyCode >= 48 and keyCode <= 57):
        if self.searchString == "":
            self.searchString = chr(event.GetKeyCode())
        elif (now - self.lastKeyDown) < 2:
            self.searchString += str(chr(event.GetKeyCode()))
        else:
            self.searchString = str(chr(event.GetKeyCode()))
    else:
        event.Skip()
        return
    self.lastKeyDown = now
    self.GetItem(self.searchString, self.GetRootItem())
```

Comment: I've already tried this. When I type characters, the selection change works properly. But when I press the arrow keys there is a really strange behaviour. When I raise an Exception in an else-statement, the tree behaves like I want to. It seems that I have to abort my event handling.